# Help writing a mysql query

Tags: mysql

I'm getting a headache from this query, I have no idea how to solve it. Perhaps I should just do the math in PHP but I can't seem to do that either.. It's BRAINBREAKING.

I need data from combining two tables:

event_hotel_reservation:

[image: event_hotel_reservation]

and hotel_room_type:

[image: hotel_room_type]

I want to write a query which shows me the total beds per day per hotel. The total beds can be found by doing `totalGuests * capacity`.

I then want to order them by day, so I know how many beds I need to book per day, per hotel.

This is the query I tried, but failed miserably:

```
select ehr.day, (ehr.totalguests * hrt.capacity) as total 
from event_hotel_reservation ehr 
inner join hotel_room_type hrt on ehr.roomtypeid = hrt.roomtypeid 
group by day
```

Any help? thanks in advance.

Comment: How did your query fail?

Comment: It didn't return the values I expected. It didn't really multiply anything. The returned values per day were '0,0,0,0,3', which is definitely wrong.

Comment: are you sure it makes sense to multiply totalGuests with capacity?

Comment: Are you sure `totalGuests * capacity` will produce total beds per day? It seems wrong to me. It will produce `0,0,0,0,3`, because you have zero guests, and anything multiplied by zero will give you a zero.

Comment: I'll rethink my concept and come back to edit this question >.< thanks

Comment: @cabaret: You already have total beds in `capacity`, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, but you have to also group by hotel. Try:

```
    SELECT ehr.day, (ehr.totalguests * hrt.capacity) AS total 
      FROM event_hotel_reservation ehr 
INNER JOIN hotel_room_type hrt 
        ON ehr.roomtypeid = hrt.roomtypeid 
  GROUP BY ehr.hotelID, ehr.day
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I interpreted your schema correctly

```
select ehr.hotelid, ehr.day, 
sum(hrt.capacity) as total_capacity, 
sum(ehr.totalguests) as total_used_capacity, 
sum(hrt.capacity - ehr.totalguests) as total_free_capacity
from event_hotel_reservation ehr 
inner join hotel_room_type hrt on ehr.roomtypeid = hrt.roomtypeid 
group by ehr.hotelid, ehr.day
```

Comment: Uhh, i'm extremely confused atm so ill brb :(